# While run my test class i get System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null error in my test class

Tags: unit-test

While run my test class i get

> System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

error in my test class.

i get error from my apex class

```
public PageReference gotoTaskEdit() {
        String taskid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('taskid');
        PageReference pgr;   
        **pgr =new PageReference ('/apex/TaskEditpage?taskId='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(taskid,'UTF-8')+'&subpid='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(subPrjId,'UTF-8'));**
        return pgr;
 }
```

And i call that method in test class is

```
@isTest
private class SubprojectControllerTest{
   private static testMethod void SubprojectControlle(){
   SubprojectController objsubprojectco = new SubprojectController (sc);
   objsubprojectco.gotoTaskEdit(); 
}
```

Comment: You are getting error due to "taskid" is null and "EncodingUtil.urlEncode" this method is throwing error. To resolve the error, you have to put "taskid"  and "subpid" in test class before calling the method. So use  "Apexpages.currentpage.getParameters.put('taskid',need to generate dummy taskid in test class)" and "Apexpages.currentpage.getParameters.put('subpid',need to generate dummy subpid in test class)" and then call ur method "objsubprojectco.gotoTaskEdit();" in test class.

Comment: How can i generate dummy id's in test class for taskid and subpid??                     And could you please send me some sample dummy code for that..

Comment: @Srikanth8482 has given the answer, from there you can create dummy task and similarly you can create subpid.

Answer (score 1):

You are  getting  error because of **TASKID** is null and also **subPrjId, subpid** , try like this ...

**Note** : Before u calling your method create dummy data for your **subPrjId and subpid** just like Task i created below.

---

```
@isTest 
    private class SubprojectControllerTest{ 
    private static testMethod void SubprojectControlle(){         
    Task  tsk = new Task( );
    tsk .Type = 'Email';
    tsk .Description = ''; //string
    tsk .OwnerId = ''; //user id
    tsk .WhatId = ''; //record id
    insert tsk;

    test.startTest();
    PageReference VfPage = Page.VF_PageName; // VF_PageName: replace with your vfpage
    Test.setCurrentPage(VfPage);

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(tsk);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',tsk.id);

    SubprojectController objsubprojectco = new SubprojectController (sc);
    objsubprojectco.gotoTaskEdit();
    test.stopTest();
   }
   }
```

Comment: ok.... thanq u..

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it helps, so it will help other members too.

Comment: Your code is not going to work because `Type` is not a field on `Task`. It should be `Subject` and the parameter should be called `taskid` not `Id`.

Comment: In Task TYPE and Subject both are Fields check it = https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=task_fields.htm&language=en_US,